# How to extract sentences from one text with only 1 named entity using spaCy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have a list of sentences and I want to be able to append only the sentences with **1 "PERSON" named entity** using spaCy. The code I used was as follows:

```
test_list = []
for item in sentences: #for each sentence in 'sentences' list
  for ent in item.ents: #for each entity in the sentence's entities 
    if len(ent in item.ents) == 1: #if there is only one entity
      if ent.label_ == "PERSON": #and if the entity is a "PERSON"
        test_list.append(item) #put the sentence into 'test_list'
```

But then I get:

```
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Am I doing this wrong? How exactly would I complete this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the error because `ent in item.ents` returns a boolean result, and you can't get its length.

What you want is

```py
test_list = []
for item in sentences: #for each sentence in 'sentences' list
    if len(item.ents) == 1 and item.ents[0].label_ == "PERSON": #if there is only one entity and if the entity is a "PERSON"
        test_list.append(item) #put the sentence into 'test_list'
```

The `len(item.ents) == 1` checks if there is only one entity detected in the sentence, and `item.ents[0].label_ == "PERSON"` makes sure the first entity lable text is `PERSON`.

Note the `and` operator, both conditions must be met.

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. This better clarified what I needed to with my code. But may I ask, is there a way to include sentences with multiple entities, but only one "PERSON" entity? i.e. "John had gone to America and Europe many times."

Comment: @DawudSayeed I understand you only care to check the amount of PERSON entities, so you can use `person_ents = [e for e in item.ents if e.label_ == "PERSON"]` and then `if len(person_ents) == 1: test_list.append(item)` as the for loop body.